# Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'

Tags: swiftui

My code looks like this but I can't figure out where I went wrong:

```
@ViewBuilder
func NewTimerView() -> some View {
    VStack(spacing:15) {
        Text("Add New Timer")
            .font(.title2.bold())
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(.top,10)
    }
    .padding()
    .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
    .background {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
            .fill(Color("BG"))
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your error isn't in this code, the compiler is login as to where it is. This is why we ask for a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Start commenting out code, one set of brackets at a time, until the real error reveals itself. Also, in the code you posted, `@ViewBuilder` is unnecessary.

Comment: More info is definitely needed. You're missing a closing bracket in your example, but even after adding that the snippet compiles without problems on my end. So, what platform / os version are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong, should be:

```
struct NewTimerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:15) {
            Text("Add New Timer")
                .font(.title2.bold())
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.top,10)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
        .background {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                .fill(Color("BG"))
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```